# How do you remove the default Bootstrap 3 carousel control background gradients?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, gradient

I'm pretty sure this is the code I need to modify, but for some reason I can't get the gradients to disappear in IE. I want them completely gone!

```
.carousel-control {
text-shadow: none;
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100)
}
.carousel-control.left {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.0001)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0), color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1)
}
.carousel-control.right {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.0001)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0), color-stop(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1)
}
.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `background-image` and `filter` declarations?

Comment: I did and I got a sold blue background.

Comment: Actually, I think I finally got it! `code` filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled='false')

Comment: Nice! Now you can post your solution as the answer and accept it.

Comment: What did you exactl get? Please I still cant' remove that. Thanks!

Answer (score 117):

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
```

Comment: you may need to add !important depending on your css structure

Comment: Mine worked with a custom style that had selector "a.myStyle.carousel-control".

Comment: If want avoid dotted border on select, add outline: none.
`.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
    outline: none;
}`

Answer (score 19):

IE has a weird filter and this worked when trying to fix it in IE9 (should work for all):

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right{ 
    background: none !important;
    filter: none !important;
    progid:none !important;
}
```

Comment: `.carousel-control {
  background: none !important;
  filter: none !important; progid:none !important;
}`

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it includes reset for IE9

Answer (score 12):

I notice that this will also have this annoying dotted line box when you click it unless you add this:

All in all, this makes the buttons beautiful:

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background: none !important;
  filter: progid: none !important;
  outline: 0;
 }
.carousel .carousel-control {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is specialized mixin for resetting IE gradient (Bootstrap 3).

SASS:

```
.carousel-control {
  &.left, &.right {
    background-image: none;
    @include reset-filter();
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the most robust answer, especially if you're already using bootstrap-sass

Comment: Best answer for SASS users!

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-control {
        opacity:100;
    }
```

worked for me. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using slick,owl carousal slider if you want slider without blur.