# Removing the right and left side dark areas from bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jelontok/r2wLz6xr/) in jsfiddle and I'm trying to see if I can style the controls/arrows on the left and right side so they don't show a darker area both with and without hovering over the arrows/side area. I just want the arrows to highlight when they get hovered over.

Here is my basic carousel code

```css
.item img {width: 100%; height: auto}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You might need to change the style of <a class="left carousel-control"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove the default Bootstrap 3 carousel control background gradients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746461/how-do-you-remove-the-default-bootstrap-3-carousel-control-background-gradients)